# How can I control the size of exported image in HTML code under certain magnification value?

Tags: graphics, formatting, html

I've inserted a picture in one cell, however, when I exported the cell as HTML, the size of my image in the html  tag was doubled(the image file in HTMLFiles was the same as the original image).

I know what makes this happen:
The reason is my global magnification value is 2.

How can I control my image size?

### magnification=1

```
<img src="HTMLFiles/Untitled-1_1.gif" alt="Untitled-1_1.gif" width="800" height="427" style="vertical-align:middle" />
```

### magnification=2

```
<img src="HTMLFiles/Untitled-1_1.gif" alt="Untitled-1_1.gif" width="1600" height="854" style="vertical-align:middle" />
```

---

I like magnification=2, how can I control my image size in the cell, and make it the same as the width and height in the `<img>` tag.

[image]

Comment: When you say "global magnification value" where did you set this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Ctrl+Shift+O` and search magnification, I've added one picture, hope one can see that.

Comment: Okay, is there any reason you can't just set the Notebook magnification to 50% before saving as HTML?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard seems that doesn't work well for exporting by function `Export...` but works well by save as via `GUI`

Comment: How are you exporting with `Export`?  Are you exporting a `NotebookObject` expression?  In v7 window magnification (set with the icon) affects that as well.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah, thanks, my lapse. I export a `CellObject`.

Comment: No `CellObject` in v7 so I cannot test.  Sorry.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard fine, There are some options like `Magnification->2` in the NotebookExpression.